# Spring Security authentication filter not being called

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to add a custom filter to a Spring `HttpSecurity`. This filter must check that the username is in a list provided externaly and injected into the filter as a `Set`.

No matter where I put the filter, its method `attemptAuthentication` is never called. Here is the filter code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

public class MyRoleFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    final Set<String> authorisedUsers;

    public WhoRoleFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, Set<String> authorisedUsers) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url));
        this.authorisedUsers= authorisedUsers;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        // In BASIC authentication user:password come as Base64 in the Authorization header
        final String authorization = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String[] userPasswd = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(authorization)).split(":");
        // The docs of AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter says it must throw an exception in case authentication fails
        // https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html#attemptAuthentication-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-
        if (userPasswd.length!=2)
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad Credentials");
        if (authorisedUsers.contains(userPasswd[0])) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userPasswd[0], userPasswd[1]);
            return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
        } else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("User has not the correct role");
        }
    }

}
```

And this is how I am trying to add it to `HttpSecurity`:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/disabled")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new MyRoleFilter("**/path/services/whatever/**", this.authenticationManager() ,myUserNamesSet), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .httpBasic();
    }

}
```

I am not certain where during the build chain must the `addFilterBefore()` go. Moreover, a standard user+password aginst an LDAP server is required additionally to the usernames list filter. The LDAP authentication was alredy in place and in working order.

**Update**, this is the `configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)` at `SecurityConfig`

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    try {
        auth.ldapAuthentication()
            .userDnPatterns(ConfigurationProvider.get().getProperty(Property.PROP_LDAP_USER_BASE_DN))
            .contextSource(contextSource())
            .passwordCompare()
            .passwordAttribute(ConfigurationProvider.get().getProperty(Property.PROP_LDAP_PASSWORD_ATTRIBUTE));
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        LOG.error(exc.getMessage(), exc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question after research. This is how I had to implement `SecurityConfig` and my authentication processing filter in order to add a custom role check on to of Basic authentication using LDAP for storing user credentials.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private String Set<String> myUsers;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        myUsers = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("John","James","Jeremy"));
        try {
            auth.ldapAuthentication()
                    .userDnPatterns("ldap.user.base.dn")
                    .contextSource(contextSource())
                    .passwordCompare()
                    .passwordAttribute("ldap.password.attribute");
            auth.authenticationEventPublisher(defaultAuthenticationEventPublisher());
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            // LOG.error(exc.getMessage(), exc);
        }
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setAuthenticationConfiguration(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) {
        super.setAuthenticationConfiguration(authenticationConfiguration);
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setObjectPostProcessor(ObjectPostProcessor<Object> objectPostProcessor) {
        super.setObjectPostProcessor(objectPostProcessor);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        try {
            http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/disabled")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterAfter(new MyFilter("/services/my/path",  this.authenticationManager(), myUsers), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .httpBasic();

            http.logout().deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .invalidateHttpSession(true);
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            // LOG.error(exc.getMessage(), exc);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I had to override `successfulAuthentication` from `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` as it was always trying to perform a redirect looking for a request header containing the target URL.

```
public class MyFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    final Set<String> authorisedUsers;

    public MyFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, Set<String> authorisedUsers) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url));
        this.authorisedUsers = authorisedUsers;
        this.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        // In BASIC authentication user:password come as Base64 in the Authorization header
        final String authorization = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String authorizationBasic = authorization; 
        if (authorization.startsWith("Basic")) {
            authorizationBasic = authorization.split(" ")[1];
        }
        final String[] userPasswd = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(authorizationBasic)).split(":");
        // The docs of AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter says it must throw an exception in case authentication fails
        // https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html#attemptAuthentication-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-
        if (userPasswd==null || userPasswd.length!=2)
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad Credentials");
        if (authorisedUsers.contains(userPasswd[0])) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userPasswd[0], userPasswd[1]);
            return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
        } else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("User " + userPasswd[0] + " has not the WHO role");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `and().addFilter(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))` under `configure(HttpSecurity http)` as below. It should call the authentication Filter explicitly.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().addFilter(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager())).sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```